# .NET Web API, Return Data To Client, Then Process Transaction?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a VB.NET Web API controller, that performs two functions: when a request comes in, it processes the request, and then returns data to the client. The client service consuming the process has a timeout of 1.5s, in most cases my controller responds in time, however under some circumstances the controller does not respond in time.

According to telemetry the heavy lifting that will cause it to take to long to return can actually be processed after i return to the client, I've tried to modify the controller, but this has not improved the response time:

```
 Public Class SMSController
    Inherits TwilioController
    <HttpPost>
    Public Async Function Index() As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of ActionResult)
        Dim tml = New MessagingResponse()
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form("From")) Then Return TwiML(tml.Message(Constants.smsError))
        Dim smsFrom As String = Replace(Request.Form("From"), "+1", "")
        Dim db As New DB_ENTITY
        Dim r = (From p In db.Task Where p.smsFrom = smsFrom).FirstOrDefault()
        If IsNothing(r) Then
            Try
                Return TwiML(tml.Message(Constants.smsError))
            Finally
               HeavyLifting()
            End Try
        End If
        '// Code shortened for brevity
```

It is my understanding that this should return the twilio markup to the client, then run the `heavylifting()` but this does not seem to be the case.

The heavy stuff returns in time the majority of the time, so i don't want to task it and process it later, is there a better way i can return the markup to the client and then perform the processing?